# Is there any way to change the default app installation directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation, package-management

I have a laptop with 256GB solid state drive and 1 tb hard disk drive as I want some apps like vs code and blender to be installed on my hard disk drive rather then installing on my solid state drive. Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory that is possible, at least with rpm packages (`--relocate`, `--badreloc`) but AFAIK only very few packages support that. And if you override that it probably gets even worse.

The easier way may be to first install it the regular way and then identify files and folders which use much space. Those can be moved to the other disk. After that you can make them available under their official paths via symlink, subvolume mount (btrfs) or bind mount.

Unexpected effects are possible, though, especially with upgrades. I consider mounts to be less dangerous than symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention two standalone softwares, I propose this:

1. Download the compressed version of vscode and blender.
2. Decompress them in your hard disk, preferably under some main folder.
3. Create a symlink of the executables in `/usr/bin`
4. Create `.desktop` files of each executable and place them in `~/.local/share/applications`.